# Celery not registering tasks

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, task, registration

My current program setup consists of a run.py file with the following contents:

```py
from cocapi.task import my_add

from cocapi import app
print(app.tasks.keys())

res = my_add.delay(1, 2)
print(res.get())
```

I then have a directory called `cocapi`, the contents of the `__init__.py` file are shown below:

```py
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('cocapi')
app.config_from_object('cocapi.celeryconfig')
```

The `task.py` file can be found in the module  directory with the following contents:

```py
from cocapi import app

@app.task
def my_add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Upon running the `run.py` file I get the following error:

`celery.exceptions.NotRegistered: 'cocapi.task.my_add'`

However, the print statement from the `run.py` file is showing that the task had been added to the application:

`dict_keys(['celery.chord_unlock', 'celery.group', 'celery.map', 'cocapi.task.my_add', 'celery.chain', 'celery.starmap', 'celery.accumulate', 'celery.chord', 'celery.backend_cleanup', 'celery.chunks'])`

Additionally, I start up a RabbitMQ worker using the following command:

`celery -A cocapi worker --loglevel=info`

What could be going wrong here? Thanks for any help that you can provide me!

Comment: When you start the worker like you mentioned - `celery -A cocapi worker --loglevel=info` - does it show all the expected tasks in the list (that is what Celery worker does on startup)?

Comment: can you share your celery config file? did you try to include the task's file? something like `app = Celery('cocapi', include='task.py')`

Comment: @finlay-morrison did you try my suggestion?